# How can I specify the name of a mounted drive in Windows when mounting programmatically?

Tags: windows, perl, mount

I am writing a perl routine that mounts specific drives at startup. However, when the drives are mounted, they appear in "My Computer" with odd names like "dir$ at 'machinename' (H:)".

Is there a way in perl or C to specify this string (or just the 'dir$' part?) at mount-time?

Comment: I doubt it -- don't those strings come from the share name specified by the remote machine?

Comment: I thought that was the right hand side ('machinename'), not the left.

Comment: How are you mounting the drives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching, one way to do it is by monkeying with the registry--not a great method, but it works

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\DriveIcons\D\DefaultLabel]
```

will set the visible label for the D: drive, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You question is not entirely clear to me, but do you mean something like [File::Spec](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Spec.html)'s `splitpath` method?

> **splitpath**
>
> Splits a path in to volume, directory,
>   and filename portions. On systems with
>   no concept of volume, returns '' for
>   volume.
>
> 1. ($volume,$directories,$file) = File::Spec->splitpath( $path );
> 2. ($volume,$directories,$file) = File::Spec->splitpath( $path, $no_file
>      );
>
> For systems with no syntax
>   differentiating filenames from
>   directories, assumes that the last
>   file is a path unless $no_file is true
>   or a trailing separator or /. or /..
>   is present. On Unix, this means that
>   $no_file true makes this return ( '',
>   $path, '' ).
>
> The directory portion may or may not
>   be returned with a trailing '/'.
>
> The results can be passed to catpath()
>   to get back a path equivalent to
>   (usually identical to) the original
>   path.